# Deserializar XML polimórfico

Tags: java, xml, spring, jackson

Estoy intentando deserializar (con jackson) un XML con una estructura polimórfica y no soy capaz. Mi XML tiene una estructura de este tipo:

```
<data>
    <name>My Name</name>
    <option>...</option>
    <option>...</option>
    <option>...</option>
    <option>...</option>
    <item>...</item>
    <item>...</item>
    <item>...</item>
    <item>...</item>
    <option>...</option>
    <option>...</option>
</data>
```

He visto este enlace http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization pero no he conseguido hacerlo funcionar.

Alguien tiene experiencia deserializando XML de este tipo (o algún ejemplo de como hacerlo)?

Comment: Y que valores pueden ser `option` e `item`, ademas, has intentado usar una clase root? podrias mostrarla

Comment: Los objetos option e item tienen propiedades distintas que tampoco vienen al caso (no quería hacer la pregunta muy pesada). Lo cierto es que no he usado una clase root. Voy a probar tal y como propones a ver que tal. Gracias @jasilva

Answer (score 0):

Me voy a responder a mi mismo. Finalmente lo resolví usando JAXB, lo he intentado con Jackson y no he sido capaz.

La forma que usado para resolverlo ha sido creando una clase base para los dos objetos que tenía definida así:

```
@XmlSeeAlso({Operator.class, OperatorItem.class})
public class BaseOperator {

}
```

y en la propiedad de la clase que contiene la lista con los dos tipos, utilizar el atributo XMLElements de esta forma:

```
@XmlElements({
    @XmlElement(name = "operator", type = Operator.class),
    @XmlElement(name = "item", type = OperatorItem.class)
})
private List<BaseOperator> operators = new ArrayList<BaseOperator>();
```

Espero que os sirva.